# Docker : Cannot remove dangling containers

Tags: docker

when i try to execute a command to list all the dead or dangling docker in volume and delete it directly :

**docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)**

and it will throw an exception which is :

**Unable to remove a directory of out the Docker root /var/lib/docker: /home/docker/volumes/ffdffa840a2fb54799aab3de565d02458915f460dc785b7288926729251e1b61/_data**

Comment: I'm now running in the same issue on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, below work for me

```
cd /home/docker/volumes/
rm -rf $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a known issue.  I have this little helper for some time now:

```
#!/bin/bash

imgs=$(docker images | awk '/<none>/ { print $3 }')
if [ "${imgs}" != "" ]; then
   echo docker rmi ${imgs}
   docker rmi ${imgs}
else
   echo "No images to remove"
fi

procs=$(docker ps -a -q --no-trunc)
if [ "${procs}" != "" ]; then
   echo docker rm ${procs}
   docker rm ${procs}
else
   echo "No processes to purge"
fi
```

Running it at most twice in succession seems to clean up most issues. I think I wrote it based on some blog posts two+ years ago.

Comment: is this applicable for removing the Docker volume which is orphan and no longer being used by the container?

Comment: Yup, that is what I use it for: "purge whatever is unused".

Comment: Dirk, wouldn't that just be for images (vs volumes)?

Comment: It does two passes, one `docker rmi` and one `docker rm`.  I have been using that for years to clean both _images_ and _containers_.

Comment: The question is about *volumes*, not *images* or *containers*.